# Run NPM script ONLY when a JS file is staged

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, pre-commit-hook

Is there a way to run an NPM script ONLY when a JS file is staged? Specifically, after a `pre-commit` git hook (using [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky)). I have the following scripts in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest",
    "precommit": "npm test",
    ...
},
```

I want to be able to only run `jest` if there are JS files staged. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this?

https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged

You can configure it like so:

> Add `"lint-staged": { "*.js": "eslint" }` to `package.json`

Comment: I have and I tried this. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for my desired output. This will run any npm script, but it will not break on failed output. It just continues on with the commit.

Comment: More specifically: `npm run test-no-commit-on-test-fail`

Comment: It's been a while since the last activity but I would like to point you in the direction of `husky`, a `node` `git` `hook` library. One would have to get to the bottom of 'which staged changes do I have' but the lib _should_ be a step in the right direction, especially for more custom/heavier use cases.